# Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003, registry

While giving permissions to the 'defaultAppPool' user I am getting the message 'There is no such global user or group: DefaultAppPool.' Can anyone help me here!
However, using command 'net localgroup "Performance Monitor Users" DefaultAppPool /add' I am able to resolve the error but i am facing this problem in Windows Server 2003/IIS 6.0. Here, I am always prompted as 'There is no such global user or group: DefaultAppPool.' I have also added the 'Network Service' but no avail.

Comment: You do not need to add NetworkService, to fix the problem you can set the Identity of the Application Pool to NetworkService (allthough it is could be a security leak).

Comment: it works fine for me thanks

Answer (score 22):

You have to add the user that your `DefaultAppPool` is configured to use. Check the `Identity` of your `DefaultAppPool` and add that to the `Performance Monitor Users` group.

Now, I can't say that correctly adding the user to the group will fix your real issue. I am getting the same error with performance counters even through my app pool users have been added to this group.

Comment: I had the same problem but found out the IIS service needed to be restarted after the user was added to the group for it to take effect.

Comment: Added "IIS Apppool\DefaultAppPool", restarted IIS (from Service Manager), still doesn't work.

Comment: Same problem but was using a domain account.  I had to restart the server (app pool, web site was not enough).

Comment: Note that your application may not use DefaultAppPool, but for example "ASP.NET v4.0", in that case use "IIS AppPool\ASP.NET v4.0", also note that windows restart is necessary.

Comment: IIS Reset was not enough.  A reboot cleared it (Server 2016, EC2).

Comment: I made the above changes, it didn't work. I restarted the server and it worked.