# How to set right Windows Service permissions

Tags: c#, windows, security

We have custom Windows Service on C#. This service accessing some URLs and starting some predefined local scripts.

I'm picking up project from the guy who leaving the team. We changing service's user to my account. The previous guy used to run service from administrator account, but it's a violation of the security policy. I'm trying to do this right way.

The problem is, this service has no permission to access registry with errors.
There are exceptions inside C# service:

```
'Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied'
```

The question is what permission are we missed for this user account or how to find it out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865999/access-to-the-registry-key-global-is-denied)

Comment: "Changing service's user to my account" is most definitely *not* the right way.  What happens the next time you change your password?  Try the local service account, or create a dedicated account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the most of the results from the Google for query 'Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied' shows, this message mean 'user has no access rights to the performance information.'