# Azure App Service: using PerformanceCounters

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-performancecounters

I am trying to setup my Azure Web App to include the use of a third party software, which seems to require access to PerformanceCounters. Locally this works fine, but when I run it in Azure I get the following error:

```
[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.]
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str) +5230217
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.InternalGetValue(String name, Object defaultValue, Boolean doNotExpand, Boolean checkSecurity) +11769029
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue(String name) +40
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceMonitor.GetData(String item) +102
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceData(String item) +186
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable() +105
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String category) +17
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String machine, String category) +61
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCounterInstances(String categoryName, String machineName) +70
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames() +25
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301640/access-to-the-registry-key-global-is-denied-when-accessing-performance-count), I should configure IIS to allow access to the app pool/user, but I don't think that is possible for a Azure Web App. Is there a way to get performance counters working in my situation?

Comment: Try adding the cache client application account to the following groups: Performance Monitor Users group and Performance Log Users group, and Restart the cache client application.

Comment: Try wbemtest "Win+R" and type wbemtest and check for an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, Performance Counters are accessible through WMI:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392397(v=vs.85).aspx

WMI is restricted in the App Service sandbox.
From https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#access-to-out-of-process-com-servers:

> Access to out-of-process COM servers
>
> Windows Servers have a bunch of COM servers configured and available for consumption by default; however the sandbox prevents access to all out-of-proc COM servers. **For example, a sandboxed application cannot call into WMI, or into MSIServer.**

From Kudu:

```
PS D:\home> Get-Counter -Counter "\processor(_total)\% processor time"
Get-Counter : The specified object was not found on the computer.


PS D:\home> Get-WmiObject -Class WIN32_OperatingSystem
Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 
(E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

If you absolutely have to use the 3rd party software, look at Azure Cloud Services (with a Web Role). You have full control over the OS there while still being PaaS.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. I previously ran the software using a Worker Role in a Cloud Service, but for testing it was overkill, so I wanted something less costly. Seems I'm out of luck.

Comment: E_ACCESSDENIED = tears. the standard app service metric CPU_TIME is just not the same as "Processor/% User Time"