# Exception occured when call cmldet powershell c# create New-mailBox

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

trying to execute cmdlet exchange powershell new-mailBox failed in c# - remote access on exchange 2016 server

Add user account to the different group for access right execution

```
        string connectionUri = "http://xxx.contosoe.com/powershell/";
        string loginPassword = "password";

        SecureString secpassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in loginPassword)
        {
            secpassword.AppendChar(c);
        }

        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(@"doamin\user", secpassword);

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);
        PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        powershell.Commands.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("ActiveDirectory");
        // 
        PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
        command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
        command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
        command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", new Uri(connectionUri));
        command.AddParameter("Credential", credential);
        command.AddParameter("Authentication", "KerBeros");
        powershell.Commands = command;

        runspace.Open();
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        Collection<PSObject> result = powershell.Invoke();
        if (powershell.Streams.Error.Count > 0 || result.Count != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Fail to establish the connection");
        }

        powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        command = new PSCommand();
        command.AddCommand("Set-Variable");
        command.AddParameter("Name", "ra");
        command.AddParameter("Value", result[0]);
        powershell.Commands = command;
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        powershell.Invoke();

        powershell = PowerShell.Create();
        command = new PSCommand();
        command.AddScript("Import-PSSession -Session $ra");
        powershell.Commands = command;
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        powershell.Invoke();

        Pipeline pipeLine = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        var emailCreateCommand = CreateEmailCommand("name", "displayName", "alias");

        pipeLine.Commands.Add(emailCreateCommand);
        Collection<PSObject> result_ = pipeLine.Invoke();
```

stack trace....
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for  'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Common.NewUserBase'. --->
    System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied.
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.InternalGetValue(String name, Object defaultValue, Boolean doNotExpand, Boolean checkSecurity)
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue(String name)
    System.Diagnostics.PerformanceMonitor.GetData(String item)
    System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceData(String item)
    System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
    System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CategoryExists(String machine, String category)
    System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(String categoryName, String machineName)
    Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Common.NewUserBase..cctor()

```
Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Common.NewUserBase.InternalBeginProcessing()
Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewMailboxBase.InternalBeginProcessing()
Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewMailboxOrSyncMailbox.InternalBeginProcessing()
Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.<BeginProcessing>b__83_1()
Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.InvokeRetryableFunc(String funcName, Action func, Boolean terminatePipelineIfFailed)
```

Comment: Translate your stack trace

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301640/access-to-the-registry-key-global-is-denied-when-accessing-performance-count

Comment: I already try this solution but the error persist. Thank you for your response